# How to get more than 20 results for nearby places using google api

Tags: php, pagination, google-places-api

```
<?php
{
    $references = array();
    $names = array();

    $lat="26.177194999999998";
    $long="91.77591333333334";
    $count=0;

    $placeSearchURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$lat,$long&radius=10000&types=mosque&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyASP02W3Qwb75Ruep3isiGstqA7Y2HXjGw";

    $placeSearchJSON = file_get_contents($placeSearchURL);
    $dataArray = json_decode($placeSearchJSON);

    if(isset($dataArray->status) &&$dataArray->status == "OK") {
        foreach( $dataArray->results as $details) {         
            array_push($references, $details->reference);
            array_push($names, $details->name);
        }
    }        
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        echo $name."<br>";
    }    
    echo "next token".$dataArray->next_page_token."<br>";
    if(!empty($dataArray->next_page_token)) {
        echo "in the if statement"."<br>";
        $placeSearchURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$lat,$long&radius=10000&types=mosque&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyASP02W3Qwb75Ruep3isiGstqA7Y2HXjGw&nextpage=".$dataArray->next_page_token;
        $placeSearchJSON = file_get_contents($placeSearchURL);
        //echo "hello";
        $dataArray = json_decode($placeSearchJSON);

        if(isset($dataArray->status) &&$dataArray->status == "OK") {
            foreach( $dataArray->results as $details) {
                array_push($references, $details->reference);
                array_push($names, $details->name);
            }
        }
        echo "hello<br>"; 
    }

    foreach ($names as $name) {
        echo $name."<br>";  
    }
    echo "next token".$dataArray->next_page_token."<br>";

    if(!empty($dataArray->next_page_token)) {
        echo "in the if statement"."<br>";
        $placeSearchURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$lat,$long&radius=10000&types=mosque&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyASP02W3Qwb75Ruep3isiGstqA7Y2HXjGw&nextpage=".$dataArray->next_page_token;

        $placeSearchJSON = file_get_contents($placeSearchURL);
        //echo "hello";
        $dataArray = json_decode($placeSearchJSON);
        if(isset($dataArray->status) &&$dataArray->status == "OK") {
            foreach( $dataArray->results as $details) {

            array_push($references, $details->reference);
            array_push($names, $details->name);
        }
    }
    echo "hello<br>";         
}
foreach ($names as $name) {
    echo $name."<br>";
}
?>
```

I get the same 20 results every time, and I have used pagination as you can see in my code. Every time I print the next page token I get a different one.

I would really appreciate if someone could point out the error in my code because I am stuck with this for quite some time. You are also most welcome to give any kind of relevant suggestion.

Comment: this is same ` $lat="26.177194999999998";$long="91.77591333333334";` :'( :'(

Comment: as i have already written i am try to use pagination we can get at most 60 results using it 20 per page so i am loding the data from three pages

Comment: @FerozAkbar any advice reharding it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use pagetoken instead of nextpage in your url string  and in the last two calls give only api key and page token as parameter and after each api call use sleep(2) i tried your code and it works perfectly when the following changes are made.happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

//echo"hello"; 
   $references = array();
     $names = array();

    $lat="26.177194999999998";
    $long="91.77591333333334";
     $count=0;

 $placeSearchURL ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=26.177194999999998,91.77591333333334&radius=3000&types=mosque&key=your APIkey";
    $placeSearchJSON = file_get_contents($placeSearchURL);

    $dataArray = json_decode($placeSearchJSON);


        foreach( $dataArray->results as $details) {

            //echo $details->place_id;
            array_push($references, $details->place_id);

        }



       foreach($references as $reference)
       {

        $count=$count+1;
        //echo $count."  ";
              $placeSearchURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=".$reference."&key=your apikey";
          $placeSearchJSON = file_get_contents($placeSearchURL);
          $dataArray = json_decode($placeSearchJSON);

          echo $dataArray->result->name."<br>";
          echo "lat  ".$dataArray->result->geometry->location->lat."<br>";
           echo "lon  ".$dataArray->result->geometry->location->lng."<br>";
           echo "address  ".$dataArray->result->formatted_address."<br>";
          echo "<br>";

        }
```

?>

basically i wanted to find a way to get more than 20 places of type masjid so i first used radar search to get placeids and then for each placed_id got the information and best part is you can get arount 200 results of nearby places